# Why is ideal wavelet selection a least-squares estimate?

Tags: wavelets, least-squares

In their classic paper "Ideal spatial adaptation by wavelet shrinkage" (http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/81/3/425.short?rss=1&ssource=mfr), Donoho and Johnstone make the following statements:

Let $f$ be a piecewise polynomial function. If the list of true discontinuities in $f$ was known via an oracle, we could use a least squares estimate for each of the segments to obtain an estimate $\hat f$ with ideal risk $\sigma^2 L(D+1)$, where $L$ is the number of segments and $D$ the degree of the polynomial. They call this "piecewise polynomial adaptation".

Later on, they consider a hypothetical method called "selective wavelet reconstruction". For each wavelet function $W_{j,k}$, and the wavelet coefficients

$w_{j,k} = \theta_{j,k} + z_{j,k}$

where $\theta$ and $z$ denote the signal and noise part of the coefficient, this method obtains a subset $\delta^\star$ of wavelet coefficient indices $(j,k)$ from an oracle such that a wavelet is in the list iff $\theta_{j,k} \neq 0$. In other words, it keeps those wavelets that span a discontinuity in $f$, hence removing all coefficients that are due to noise only.

They then go on to claim that

> because of the orthogonality of the $(W_{j,k})$, $\sum_{(j,k)\in \delta^\star} w_{j,k} W_{j,k}$ is the least-squares estimate of $f$ and [the risk] $R(T(y, \delta^\star), f) = n^{-1}\{\#(\delta^\star)\}\sigma^2$

I do understand how this risk is derived (the retained coefficients are still contaminated by noise), but I don't see why selective wavelet reconstruction would be an LSE? The risk they derive for this method is similar, but not equal to the one for polynomial adaptation, which clearly IS an LSE.

I am clearly missing something here. Could somebody please explain how one would derive the second method to yield an LSE, and why that would be different from polynomial adaptation via least squares?

Comment: You didn't explain what is "the signal and noise part". I could take 1 hour for reading the paper, or you could explain.

Comment: Certainly :-) The wavelet transform is linear, so it acts on the signal and noise part of the data seperately. More specifically, for data $x = f+\epsilon$, where $f$ is the signal and $\epsilon$ is i.i.d. centered Gaussian noise, and a wavelet function $\psi_{j,k}$, $w_{j,k} = \langle x, \psi_{j,k}\rangle = \langle f+\epsilon, \psi_{j,k}\rangle =  \langle f, \psi_{j,k}\rangle + \langle \epsilon, \psi_{j,k}\rangle = \theta_{j,k} + z_{j,k}$.

Comment: in eq (4) what is understand is that we have a signal model $F(n )= f(n) + e(n)$ where $e(n)$ is i.i.d. Gaussian and $f(n) = \sum_i p_i(n) 1_{n \in T_i}$ where $p_i$ are some polynomials ($f$ is piecewise polynomial) and  and we want to LSE $f(n)$ from $F(n)$ given an oracle telling us $T_i$, so that we can use the LSE polynomial regression on each $P_i(n) =p_i(n)+e(n)$ to recover an estimate $\hat{p_i}(n)$ of $p_i(n)$ and a global estimate $\hat{f}(n) =  \sum_i \hat{p_i}(n) 1_{n \in T_i}$ whose square error $\|\hat{f}-f\|^2$ will be much better than without the oracle.

Comment: Then it describes a wavelet implementation of this, but I don't follow it. Can you give the clues ? It computes the WT of $F(n)$ and keeps only the main coefficients ?

Comment: It keeps those coefficients that span across the discontinuities. If we know the breakpoints from an oracle, an LSE for each of the piecewise polynomials yields an ideal risk of $\sigma^2L(D+1)$. My problem is with the claim that an oracle with knowledge of $f$ that gives you an optimal subset of wavelet coefficients, this somehow also yields an LSE (why?), but for some reason that LSE has a different ideal risk. So two different oracles for two different methods both yield an LSE, but have different ideal risk?

Comment: And a mean squared error $n^{-1} \#T_i \sigma^2$ is more or less what we would get if we had an oracle as I wrote. So you are saying it continues with an oracle giving the best wavelet coefficients (those encoding most of the signal $f(n)$) instead of the $T_i$ ?

Comment: Well they mention that the wavelet basis is orthonormal so that each wavelet coefficient has the same variance (that's a property of decorrelated noise : it stays decorrelated noise under any orthonormal transformation), and if you keep only $1/K$ of them you will avoid $\frac{K-1}{K}$ of the noise and the MSE will be divided by $K$ (assuming the signal is 100% supported on the wavelet coefficients you kept, which is not very realistic)

Comment: Yeah, I get that. My problem is why the wavelet method is an LSE in the first place. I've tried to write up an easier version of their argument: assume f to be piecewise polynomial as above, with breakpoints/discontinuities $T_i$. If an oracle knows the true breakpoints, we can use regression to get an LSE of each polynomial, and thus an LSE of $f$. No problem with that. The wavelet method is based on the fact that the signal coefficients for any wavelet whose support remains within a single $p_i$ and ...

Comment: ...hence does not go across any $T_i$, are 0 ($\langle p_i, \psi_{j,k}\rangle = 0$), so for those we have $\langle y, \psi_{j,k}\rangle = \langle \epsilon, \psi_{j,k}\rangle$. So if the oracle gives us the breakpoints, we can throw away all coefficients for which $\langle y, \psi_{j,k}\rangle = \langle \epsilon, \psi_{j,k}\rangle$. The remaining coefficients, i.e. the ones for which the wavelet function goes across at least one $T_i$, are kept, and have a noise and a signal part. The inverse wavelet transform yields a regression $\hat f$.

Comment: Somehow, this is supposed to be an LSE, but with different risk than piecewise polynomial regression.